# Image not uploading using flask (shows no file selected when I click upload). IDE shows 302

Tags: python, flask, edge-detection

I am learning flask, trying to write code for edge detection in an image, and let users upload the image, using flask. I believe I'm unable to upload the image correctly, it shows 'no file selected' when I click upload. Here is my code.

```
import os.path
from io import BytesIO
from tempfile import mkdtemp

from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from flask import send_from_directory, redirect, send_file
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

from edge_new import edge_detector
from flask_app import UPLOAD_FOLDER

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'sib'

temp_dir = mkdtemp()
app.config[UPLOAD_FOLDER] = 'temp_dir'


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "The app is up and running. Go to /edge for functionality"


@app.route('/edge', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def process_img():
    """
    Function takes an image,
    finds edges in the image,
    returns processed image for download.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Check if image exists
        if 'img' not in request.files:
            flash("Image not found"), 400
            return redirect('/edge')

        image = request.files['img']

        # Check if image selected

        if image.filename == "":
            flash("No selected image"), 400
            return redirect('/edge')

        # Save the image

        image_path = secure_filename(image.filename)
        path = os.path.join(temp_dir, image_path)
        image.save(path)

        # Find edges in the image using edge_detector function

        processed_image = edge_detector(path)  # processed_img is ndarray

        # Save the processed image

        
        send_file(BytesIO(processed_image), download_name='processed.jpg', mimetype='image/jpg', as_attachment=True)
        
    return render_template('index.html')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, debug=True)
```

I have tried different things. But the error stays. I have tried send_file(), send_from_directory(), cv2.imwrite() but I'm not sure what works. This is my index.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload Example</title>
    <style>
    .ok{

        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .op{
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: -70px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: yellow;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h1> Uploading and Returning Files With a Database in Flask </h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/edge" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input class="ok" type="file" name="file">
            <button class="op">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of the input fields can be queried using the name attribute. Unfortunately, you have set the attribute to `file` for the input field and are requesting `img` from `request.files`. Either you change the attribute in the html code to `img` or ask for `file` on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code by running it.
Your endpoint /edge is trying to get **img** in if condition and block:

```
if 'img' not in request.files:
    flash("Image not found"), 400
    return redirect('/edge')

image = request.files['img']
```

While you are sending file as name="file"

```
<input class="ok" type="file" name="file">
```

You can correct it by updating index.html input code line:
(See name="img" instead of name="file")

```
<input class="ok" type="file" name="img">
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Vinay, and Detlef. I made the change as suggested, it worked. I got some other error this time :( I believe there is some other issue in my code as well. I'll troubleshoot and ask again if I need help. Thanks a lot for all the help Vinay :)Cheers